# API working EUREKA - Error when using @Component

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, netflix-eureka

Guys

I have a microservice that works using the eureka architecture (discovery, gateway) and the database connection is in another service. When I start the application I want it to call a method for that I use @Component in the class and @Bean in the method. However, when called, it still hasn't completed the registrations in Eureka and when I get to the @Component lifecycle, I still don't have the connection to the database.

I need something that waits for the application to upload everything before calling this service.

Java11

Comment: Simply: [`@DependsOn("dataSource")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) (you should know the name of the data source to depend on) ..or more complex for "intialized database": https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.dependencies.depends-on-initialization-detection

Comment: I try but not worked

Comment: you *know* the name of the data source?